# Defining addition using unary functions and currying in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, currying

I'm a Haskell beginner trying to understand currying.
I've seen examples that are supposed to demonstrate it, but they involve binary operators, which themselves are curried, plunging my mind into infinite recursion.
If operators in Haskell are functions, and all functions are unary and curried, could I define my own addition function in terms of only unary functions?

Comment: Do you mean something like `plus :: (Num a) => a -> (a -> a)`?

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the type of (+).

Comment: It can be useful for you to read this blog post about function arguments in Haskell: http://blog.tmorris.net/posts/haskell-functions-take-one-argument/index.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

```
add :: Num a => a -> a -> a
add = \a -> \b -> a + b
```

This is also an example of a closure.  `\b -> a + b` has access to `a` through a closure because a is defined outside the scope of that lambda.

**Edit**

These are called Peano number values

```
data Nat = Zero | Succ Nat                   

add Zero = \n -> n                                                              
add (Succ a) = \b -> Succ (add a b)                                             

toNat 0 = Zero                                                                  
toNat n = Succ (toNat (n-1))                                                    

fromNat Zero = 0                                                                
fromNat (Succ n) = 1 + fromNat n  


λ: fromNat $ add (toNat 3) (toNat 4)
7
```

Comment: That seems like somewhat circular reasoning to me, like the examples I mention in my question... You define addition in terms of addition and you could argue that '+' is really a unary function, but that doesn't explain much...

Comment: are you saying the `+` operator or the lambdas?

Comment: I'm interested in how + could be implemented in the first place.

Comment: @user3026691: In this case your question is misleading and should actually be something like "How is `(+)` implemented in Haskell on standard types?".

Comment: @DiegoNolan That's a more long-winded way of defining addition in terms of addition again...

Comment: @DiegoNolan: `fromNat` uses `+`. I guess this won't satisfy OP either.

Comment: @Zeta That is just to print easier.  the `Nat` type and the `add` function are the only necessary functions.

Comment: @Zeta the title states accurately what I would like to achieve and the question itself rules out using the built-in binary operators to achieve it.

Comment: The Peano's add is the same as: add Zero y = y; add (Succ x) y = add (Succ y), which is again a "binary" operator...

Answer (score 2):

Functions in haskell are unary only in the sense that they look unary to the
user. The Haskell language says nothing about the implementation of those functions.
It's perfectly alright for a haskell implementation to have `(+)` implemented as a
binary function if it also provides some way to represent values like `(+) 2`. Usually
this is done by bundling the binary function and the argument list, `2` in this case.

If you really want to implement (+) in terms of unary functions only you could
do somthing like:

```
plus a b
    | a > 0 = plus (pred a) (succ b)
    | a < 0 = plus (succ a) (pred b)
    | otherwise = b
```

But I don't think this gives you anything when it comes to understanding Haskell (or Haskell implementations) better.

Comment: I realize that the actual Haskell plus operator probably boils down to some add instruction with two operands. What I was actually looking for, and was able to gather from your and DiegoNolan's answers is this: 

    `add 0 = \a -> a
    add b = \a -> succ (add a (pred b))
    add 3 4`

This demonstrates clearly that add is a unary function that returns another unary function.

When I see something like this:
    `add = \a -> \b -> a + b`
I just have to take the author's word that add doesn't actually just return a binary function.

Comment: Ok, I guess I missed the point a bit. However, It might be worth noting that the arity of a function is not dependent on the number of variables mentioned in the definition. So `add = (+)`, `add a = (+) a` and `add a b = (+) a b` all have the same type.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add tuples using curry use the following code:

```
addPair  :: Num a => (a,a) -> a    
addPair  = \(a ,b) -> a + b
```

i.e. No argument is passed in the function.